# Variables in Bash

Tags: bash, git

I have the following in my bash script

```
EXTENSIONS=(php css js)
```

Then I have this

```
declare FILE_TYPES
for EXTENSION in ${EXTENSIONS[@]}; do
  FILE_TYPES+=("'*.${EXTENSION}'")
done
```

If I `echo ${FILE_TYPES[@]}`, I get this

```
'*.php' '*.css' '*.js'
```

I want to create a `LIST` variable which will create a list of files modified by Git of certain extension. It should look like this:

```
git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- '*.php' '*.css' '*.js'
```

Note that it will not work if I run command like this:

```
git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- *.php *.css *.js
```

In my bash script I'm trying this option

```
LIST=$( git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- ${FILE_TYPES[@]})
```

But it doesn't work. I have a feeling that it creates the second version of command.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `declare FILE_TYPES` alone doesn't do anything. I think you meant to use `declare -a FILE_TYPES`, although that's not really necessary, as the assignment `FILE_TYPES+=(...)` will automatically make `FILE_TYPES` behave as if `declare -a` had been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```sh
declare FILE_TYPES
for EXTENSION in "${EXTENSIONS[@]}"; do
  FILE_TYPES+=("*.${EXTENSION}")
done
```

```sh
LIST=$( git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- "${FILE_TYPES[@]}")
```

Note the removal of the single quotes in the `FILE_TYPES` definition and the addition of the double quotes in `"${FILE_TYPES[@]}"` expansion. Also the usage of `"${EXTENSIONS[@]}"` needs also double quotes.

Comment: I'm getting `fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths` when I `echo $LIST`

Comment: @VladStratulat: Add the definition the `EXTENSIONS` variable, there must be an empty string in there.

Comment: @VladStratulat: To see what's in the do a `printf '>%s<' "${EXTENSIONS[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks @user000001. It's all working now! Massive thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the single quotes in the array values; those would be *literal* quotes, not *syntactic* quotes.  Simply ensuring that a literal `*` appears in the value is enough; then you want to quote the *expansion* of the array in order to prevent file name expansion on the result.

```
EXTENSIONS=(php css js)
declare -a FILE_TYPES

for ext in "${EXTENSIONS[@]}"; do
    FILE_TYPES+=( "*.$ext" )
done

LIST=$( git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- "${FILE_TYPES[@]}" )
```

Comment: It's all working now! Massive thanks!!! But since @user000001 was first with his answer, I'll accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

An iteration is not needed because creating files patterns from extensions is done all at once with `"${extensions[@]/#/*.}"` which replaces the start of each `extensions` array  entries with `*.`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

extensions=(php css js)

# Proper way to populate the list array from the output of git-diff
mapfile -t list < <(
  git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- "${extensions[@]/#/*.}"
)
```

For obsolete versions of bash without `mapfile`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

extensions=(php css js)

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a list < <(
  git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- "${extensions[@]/#/*.}"
)
```

Comment: It says `mapfile: command not found`

Comment: `"${extensions[@]/#/*.}"` is amazing though! Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: @VladStratulat `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a list < <(git...)` can work with obsolete 15 years old bash 3.2 version, instead of `mapfile`.

Comment: Does this do the same? `LIST=$( git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=ACMR -- "${EXTENSIONS[@]/#/*.}" )`

Comment: @VladStratulat This is different. `string=$(command)` stores the output of the command as a string; whereas: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(command)` splits each of the output lines from the command into an array of one line per entry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with git diff-filter but you can wrap variables in an array using `printf`

```sh
$ EXTENSIONS=(php css js)
$ printf "'*.%s' " $EXTENSIONS
'*.php' '*.css' '*.js'
```